# Web-scraping using datepick/calender

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerquery

I am relatively new to web-scraping. I use power-query in excel for data import from web. Though, I have done it for simple html pages, I am finding it hard for a complex page like [this](https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/dailyreport).

To get data tables, a date has to be picked from calendar on the web page. For.eg. 31 Jul 2019. The URL remains unchanged.

When I establish a link in power-query, I do not get any value or table. Pl see below snapshot

[Snapshot - Blank table as shown in PowerQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIEIf.jpg)

Please let me know what is solution? I want all the tables for a date and then loop for multiple dates.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge with web scraping is that every page has something specific to it.
To be able to scrape the reports you will need to find out how the web application is loading them from the server (in this case), using the network tab of the browser.

I noticed that when clicking the view report for the rivers this url is called:

```
https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/rivergreport
```

for rain reports:

```
https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/raingreport
```

for Reservoir:

```
https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/reservoirgreport
```

for remarks:

```
https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/remarksreport
```

for forecast:

```
https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/weather_report
```

for special alert:

```
https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/special_alert
```

Right click -> copy curl will give you the curl request in chrome, which then you can port to any language you like, here is an example for the river report in python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'csrf_cookie_name': 'c00e8a9a3a049ed2d89b621b6c6912d1' #I think thie can be hardcoded
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'# User agent not necessary needed
}

data = {
  'river_date': '2019-08-02', # this is the date you select from the calendar
  'submit': 'View Report', # the report type, this is the first table
  'csrf_test_name': 'c00e8a9a3a049ed2d89b621b6c6912d1'
}

response = requests.post('https://www.wbiwd.gov.in/index.php/applications/rivergreport', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

html = response.text # html which is in fact the contents of the table that is displayed aget you request the report

print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

all_tr = soup.find_all('tr') # these are the table rows for the river data

for tr in all_tr:
    print(tr)
```

In order for this script to work you will need python3 installed with pip, there are plenty of good tutorials out there on how to set this up.

then in command line just run:

```
pip install requests beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine, copied the whole code in code.py, and then executed 'python3 code.py' in the terminal, i see the td's

Comment: You should just download and IDE like pycharm and work with it.

Comment: Just download pycharm and run the code:
In case you don believe me here is the resulting html https://pastebin.com/qjFYDjVm

Comment: Thanks for sharing the html. I am getting the results now. The same as listed in above link. Hate to bother you with this, but **how can I make a table out of it in PowerQuery**. The same as on source webpage. I would like to buildup a database for different dates in excel or csv. Pls can you help me in tweaking this code to include a date range and output file in txt. I am sorry for this request.

Comment: Just wrap this in method that accepts a date as parameter and call it multiple times for each day in your period. To me it seems my post answers the initial question, now you are facing different problems which might be addressed in different question or just search in google